# Enable Navigation inside a predefine callback function

Tags: dart, flutter, speech-recognition

My intention is to enable navigation on voice commands. And as to catch the voice command as a text I use the dependency called "speech_recognition" and it has a listener named "setRecognitionResultHandler" which outputs a text as a result.

```
void activateSpeechRecognizer() {
 _speech = new SpeechRecognition();
 _speech.setRecognitionResultHandler(onRecognitionResult);
}
```

In the "onRecognitionResult" method if the use says "Home" I wants to navigate to that particular screen. And currently for some reason its not working. Code as bellow, help would much appreciate.

```
void onRecognitionResult(String text) {
 if (text == "Home") {
    Builder(builder: (context) {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
    });

  stop();

}
```

Comment: In `onRecognitionResult` does `text` have any value?

Comment: yes it converts speech in to text